# How to close an Android Service that adds a system overlay view after phone sleep and wake up?

Tags: android, service, overlay, sleep, wakeup

I have an Android service that adds a system overlay view (TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT) in the *onCreate* method

```
WindowManager.addView(mOverlayView, mLayoutParams);
```

and removes it in the *onDestroy* method using

```
WindowManager.removeView(mOverlayView);
```

When the view is double tapped, it's removed from the screen by closing the service using

```
stopSelf();
```

The overlay view keeps the screen on by using

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Now, after I press the Power button to put the phone to sleep, then press it again to wake it up, after unlocking, the overlay view is still open and over the screen.

How can I make the service stop itself when/after I press the Power button and the phone goes to sleep? I don't want the overlay view to be visible on screen after waking up and unlocking the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for `ACTION_POWER_OFF` and/or `ACTION_POWER_ON` broadcasts. Note that AFAIK you can only register for those from your service via `registerReceiver()`, not via your manifest. Since your service is already running, this shouldn't be an issue. When you get the broadcast, stop the service.